# "Then I should see" Capybara step is being too specific about scope

Tags: cucumber, capybara

My page has a `<th>` tag that has "attendance" as its CSS class. The following Cucumber step fails:

```
Then I should see "Name" within "th"
```

while this one passes:

```
Then I should see "Name" within "th.attendance"
```

Do I really have to use this level of specificity? I feel like, for Cucumber, that's requiring too much knowledge of the underlying code being tested and it should be a bit more generic.

In other words, how would I say "Just find '[value]' within any 'th' tag"? And am I wrong for wanting to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following. It finds the given text within the given selector, using xpath. 
`"//#{selector}"` means that it should find tag that matches the selector.
`"[contains(text(),'#{text}']"` means that the tag text should contain the given text.

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)" within "([^"]*)"$/ do |text, selector|
  find(:xpath, "//#{selector}[contains(text(),'#{text}')]").should_not(be_nil, "Could not find the text '#{text}' within the selector '#{selector}'")
end
```